# How can I embed the new GIFV format on my webpage?

Tags: html, gif, animated-gif

Normally I would embed a gif like so.

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/awHPuBp.gifv">
```

Although I get an error that the image could not be loaded.

I'm just wondering what mark up I will need to use so that I can display the GIFV.

GIFV is created by imgur and more information can be [found here.](https://imgur.com/blog/2014/10/09/introducing-gifv/)

Comment: Any reason why this was voted down?

Comment: As it says on that site you linked to, the GIF files are encoded as _videos_, so you will have to embed them as such, not as an image.

Comment: Dat "belongs on Super User" vote though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just checked that demo site. It seems that they just convert the video to a webm video (in case of Firefox). Check this file here which comes from the demo: http://i.imgur.com/A61SaA1.webm

So I would say you could also just use the `<video>` tag to embedd those *"gif"* files. I just guess that use a feature detection and a video converting logic. No idea what this nonsense should be for.

Comment: As they explain on that site, this “nonsense” helps keeping file sizes down significantly for animations their users upload as GIFs. (The real irony here is perhaps, that presumably half of those large animations have been converted to GIF from actual videos before …)

Comment: I may should rewrite that part, I just don't understand why they call a webm/mp4 player *gifv* because that has nothing to do with gif.

Comment: I guess it’s because their user base just _loves_ their GIFs, and they wanted something that sounded familiar …

Comment: Note that you can embed using the `video` tag using the .`webm` extension, however if you try to hit the webm file directly through the web browser it will redirect to the gifv file.